# SQL - Increment based on above rows content

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if this is even possible in SQL but I'm trying to give it a go.

Here are my requirements:

- If a user has "Sick" (in Paycode) that is where the Instance and Occurence starts
- If the user has 1 day "Sick" (in Paycode) then returns (null) then off "Sick" again then the Instance increments again, whilst the Occurence stays the same
- If the user returns for 2 days or more days (null) then is "Sick" (in Paycode) again, this is a new Occurence, so the Occurance Increments and the Instance resets to 1

So basically my desired Output would look like this:

| Date | ID | Paycode | Occurrence | Instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | 1 | 1 |
| 02/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | 1 | 2 |
| 03/12/2022 | 12345 | null | null | null |
| 04/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | 1 | 3 |
| 05/12/2022 | 12345 | null | null | null |
| 06/12/2022 | 12345 | null | null | null |
| 07/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | 2 | 1 |
| 08/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | 2 | 2 |

But what I have in the minute is this:

| Date | ID | Paycode | Occurrence | Instance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | null | 1 |
| 02/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | null | 2 |
| 03/12/2022 | 12345 | null | null | null |
| 04/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | null | 3 |
| 05/12/2022 | 12345 | null | null | null |
| 06/12/2022 | 12345 | null | null | null |
| 07/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | null | 4 |
| 08/12/2022 | 12345 | Sick | null | 5 |

Partly becuase I'm unsure how to approach the Occurnence Column logic and partly because I'm unsure how to use `lag()` or `sum()` to check the two above rows

My code is as follows:

```
Select *
    , null as 'Occurrence'
    ,sum(case when a.Paycode is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by a.Date) as 'Instance'
FROM MyTable
```

So I've got so far using the `Over()` but I need to know how to reset this if the two rows above are `null` and also setup the Occurrence.

All of the dates are in ascending order by default, so you can always "check if the above two rows are null, is so do x"

Any help would really be appreciated, I've spent days trying to find a solution with no luck.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: FYI, `sum(case when a.Paycode is null then 0 else 1 end)` can be simplified to just `COUNT(a.Paycode)`

Comment: Very true, got caught up in trying so many things I didn't spot the obvious mistake, thanks!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with window functions, but I think `LAG()` will be helpful for comparing with the two previous rows.